# error while loading shared libraries: libnsd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile

I'm writing two C programs. One of them uses library `libnsd.so`. I compile two C programs using makefile which looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -O -fPIC
RM= rm
HLAV=main
HLAVO=main.o


all:lib $(HLAV)
    cc c2.c -o c2


main: $(HLAVO)

    $(CC) -L. -o $(HLAV) $(HLAVO) -lnsd

lib: libnsd.so

libnsd.so: nsd.o nd.o
    $(CC) -shared $< -o $@



 nsd.o: nsd.c nsd.h nd.h

 nd.o: nd.c nsd.h nd.h



clean:
    $(RM) -rf *.o *.so main
```

When I try to run an aplication I get an error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libnsd.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error msg means your program can't find the dynamic library `libnsd.so`.

1. You need to find the library path from your system.

If the lib is not on the regular path, I suggest put it on the regular path.

> whereis libnsd.so
>
> mv your_dir/libnsd.so /usr/local/lib

Note: If the library is does not exist on your system, you should install it first.

2. Then, use ldconfig to write the path in the config file:

> ```
> sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
> sudo ldconfig
> ```

Or if you don't have root priviledge in your workstation, you can simply change user environment path:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: What if I have libnsd.so in a current directory?

Comment: Puting the file into lib path `mv {$CUR_DIR}/libnsd.so /usr/local/lib`, then following my second step.

Comment: Any way I can put it inside makefile?

Comment: I don't know what it means in the sentence `put it inside makefile`.

Comment: I mean to do it using makefile, that finding library path or I always need to do it by using terminal?

Comment: If you have the root privilege, once you run the command `ldconfig`, the system will keep the configuration forever. If you don't, you should write the command into your shell config file. `echo "export ..." >> ~/.bashrc`. The system will run the command automatically while you login the shell.