# Program error: ./program: error while loading shared libraries: lib<xxx>.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld

(I want to make this question as generic as possible, so I will omit the name of the library that gave me the problem in the title.)

I have a project, and for that project I need a library xxx. So I download that library, compiled with the default commands (`./configure && make && make install && make clean`) - the installation procedure was documented - and tried if the example given in the documentation worked to see whether everything was correctly set up. I copied and pasted the code in a .c file and compiled it with the following command:

```
gcc -o program program.c -lxxx
```

And gcc reports no errors. However, as soon as I run the program, the following error occurs:

```
 ./program: error while loading shared libraries: lib<xxx>.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The first solution that came up to my mind was to use the gcc option -static. It worked fine and the program run correctly. But I was disappointed because that means that the library is "embedded" in the program (sorry for the wrong terminology here: I'm just a student).

So, I looked for a solution in Stack Overflow: that's what I found: [error while loading shared libraries: libnsd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677446/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libnsd-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

The library is different, but using the command

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

worked fine. In fact the libxxx.so is in /usr/local/lib (found just by using `ls /usr/local/lib | grep xxx`). The other, permanent, solution the thread suggests is to write the directory name in the /etc/ld.so.conf file:

```
sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

And that's the tricky point: ld.so.conf file contains the following line

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

and inside the directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d there is a file called libc.conf that contains the line

```
/usr/local/lib
```

I'm a bit confused about that include; if it works just as #include in C I should have /usr/local/lib in my /etc/ld.so.conf file. It appears it is not so.

Comment: did you run `rehash` after installing the library?

Comment: The issue is not specifically related to C.

Comment: [man ldconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)

Comment: @Herb Wolfe, no... I run into rehash for the first time now.. ldconfig solved the problem, but I'm going to look for that too. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/ld.so.conf` is only read by `ldconfig`, which uses it to populate the dynamic loader cache `/etc/ld.so.cache`.  If you put a library into `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` is included in the search path via that mechanism, it will only become usable (without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) if you run `ldconfig` first.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot for your answer to my thread. I did not know about the ld.so.cache... I will make some nore researches about it. Anyway, running ldconfig has solved the problem. So, every time I install a dynamic load library in /usr/local/lib I need to refresh the cache file, don't I?

Comment: Yes, run `ldconfig` after system-wide library installation is recommended.